# Unconventional Math - Anti-Number Puzzle

Tags: lateral-thinking

A mad puzzle enthusiast locks you inside a room with only one door. Next to the door is a standard numeric keypad. There is no way to escape except through the door. You find a piece of paper next to the keypad:

$181 \Rightarrow E \unicode{12288} 3$

$3 \unicode{12288} -E \Rightarrow \unicode{xFF1F}$

You turn the piece of paper over and see two more scribbles.

$E = 1$

*The answer is not in sight.*

What do you type in the keyboard to escape, and how did you figure it out?

Hint 1:

> You notice that the puzzle enthusiast had one more equation but erased it. Following the indentations on the paper, you find out that it said: $3 \unicode{x005F} 1 \Rightarrow 1A3$

Big Hint 2:

> The numbers on the keypad are all in seven-segment display. You wonder if that means anything...

Since this is my first puzzle, any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: ...I'm not noticing any suspicious blank spaces. Am I also mad?

Comment: I elaborated on the location of the spaces in hint 1.

Comment: Would using an underscore for the blank spaces work, or would it interfere with the solution?

Comment: Refer to my third hint that I just added.

Comment: For clarity, I made the white spaces more prominent.

Comment: The edit I just wrote is going to be the last hint, you're on your own from here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That big hint is a rather big hint.

Punch in

> $1801$

The first one:

> $181 \Rightarrow E \space 3$
>  Here, the 7-segment display is inverted for each number.

The second one has four entities on the left-hand side, so there will be four on the right-hand side.

> $3$ inverted gives $1$.
>  $\space$ inverted gives $8$.
>  $-$ inverted gives $0$.
>  $E$ inverted gives $1$.

---

***Old answer left in for posterity.***

Punch in:

> 12

When you consider that

> the spaces could stand for something, we can make them stand for $+17$.

This gives us:

> $181 \Rightarrow E+173$ and $3+17-E \Rightarrow ?$

From the first, we see that

> $E = 8$

which we can now plug in and solve as:

> $3+17-8 = 12$

Comment: Good try but unfortunately not the answer. I removed the math and pattern tags because I think they are misleading. The answer is less complicated and does not use conventional math. Also, your answer does not explain the third hint.

Comment: @heypeople that's because I couldn't decide if the underscore was intentional, or if it was also supposed to be a space like the others.

Comment: The underscore is intentional, it is separate from the spaces.

Comment: I just added the final clues so it should be clearer now.

Comment: Yes, I do agree it is a rather big hint. Sorry puzzling community, I didn't have enough faith in you guys.